# How to check overspeeding fine if any in Norway

Tags: driving, car-rentals, norway, fines

I would like to check if there are any overspeeding fines levied on me as I have been driving rented car of Hertz for last 7 days.

Comment: Why do you think there might be? Have you been caught by the police in a mobile speed trap or radar/camera combo?

Comment: Hertz will tell you :-)

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify